# Codeigniter session gets destroyed on AJAX success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, heroku

Iam using codeigniter framework in heroku server with AWS database..During the AJAX success function the window.location.reload(); is called and the session gets destroyed and returns to login page..Is there any way to prevent the session getting destroyed

```
              success: function(data) {                     
                    if(message == "1") {                                
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                    else {
                        var alertmessage = JSON.stringify(data['message']);
                        $("#alertmsg").text(alertmessage);
                        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                    }
                }
```

controller code

```
public function __construct()
{

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('form_validation', 'session');
        $this->load->model('client_model');

}
public function index()
{
    $myuser_id = $this->session->userdata('client_id');
    if($myuser_id!="") {        
        $client_id = $myuser_id;
        $data['client_profile'] = $this->client_model->client($client_id); 
        $this->load->view('client_profile_update',$data);
    }
    else {
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: update with your controller's code

Comment: yes updated do check it

Answer (score 0):

redirect in controller using ajax request is a bad thing.
try this,

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $myuser_id = $this->session->userdata('client_id');
    $response = array();
    if($myuser_id!="") {        
        $response['status'] = true;
    }
    else {
        $response['status'] = false;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);

}
```

JS

```
success: function(data) {   
    var res = JSON.parse(data);                  
    if(res.status) {                                
        window.location.reload();
    }
    else {
        var alertmessage = JSON.stringify(data['message']);
        $("#alertmsg").text(alertmessage);
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
    }
}
```